# WooCommerce Variation Images not displaying

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

On the single product page, when I select a color, the featured image doesn't change. WordPress has been updated to 4.6.1, WooCommerce to 2.6.2, and the Storefront theme to 2.1.2. I have deactivated all plugins except WooCommerce and am using the Storeront theme exactly as I installed it.

I cleared all caches, cleared my browser cache (Chrome, latest version),and even went so far as to re-enter all variation images for a single product. Further testing hs yielded the same result. I have no PHP errors, no errors in Dev tools, and no errors in WooCommerce System Status. After searching through a number of forums, including this one, I haven't been able to find a solution. WooCommerce documentation is limited and isn't helpful at the moment. I have done all the updating and troubleshooting per the documentation, and this feature still doesn't work. The WooThemes team is out to their annual conference until September 22nd, so I can't submit a ticket.

Has anyone had a similar problem? What did you do to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

In your list of product variations there is a little blue icon acting as an image placeholder. BE SURE TO INCLUDE LINK URL FOR IMAGES. Upload your image and then “insert”. All your variations should have an image here. On the product page the image will(should) automatically change when you select a variation.

[Further Reference](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/#add-variation-image)

[image]

Comment: Hi, Illdapt--I actually re-entered all the variation images using the UI as you showed above, but it made no difference. I suspect a possible plugin conflict, but am not yet sure. I will update when I have performed more troubleshooting.

Comment: I would assume you are correct... if you have ensured link URLs are present and also tried the re-upload. Good luck.