# WooCommerce Product image not showing

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hello after much deliberation I cannot seem to have the woocommerce product image to show. It is isn't a dead link and I have supplied the same image to all the product variations as recommended here: [WooCommerce Variation Images not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39582379/woocommerce-variation-images-not-displaying)

Any recommendations on how to fix this would be awesome!

The page is posted there: http://beta.ctda.com/product/measuring-class/

Comment: Add  this to in your functions.php

`add_filter( 'wp_calculate_image_srcset_meta', '__return_null' );`

Wordpress now adds extra meta data within images to help with responsiveness, this code will disable that for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image is there when you inspect using browser console.
It was hidden due to opacity set to 0.
Change it to 1, it will work

```
.product.has-default-attributes.has-children>.images {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is CSS issue with image, Put the following code to your css file and image is shows on the product details page.

Right now opacity of image is 0, You can change that by following...

```
.product.has-default-attributes.has-children > .images {
  opacity: unset;
}
```